# Edit .doc in Word via custom Document Library DispForm.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-2007, document

I have a document library with a workflow that dynamicly sets user permissions to edit these documents when certain criteria is met.
The users who need to edit these items are not the brightest users, so to make it failsafe and simple for them I am customizing the DispForm.aspx to only show 2 fields in the Document Library.

1. "Document" - Name of the document which is a link that opens the document in MS Word.
2. "Done?" - Yes/No tickbox.

The user gets an e-mail when they have a task assigned; the e-mail contains an URL to the custom DispForm.aspx, the user clicks the link and voila, they see the customized DispForm.aspx with only 2 fields, they know exactly what to do because they won't get distracted by an information-overdose and the only thing the user has to do is click on the document so it would open in Word, user makes changes to document, saves, ticks "yes" in the "Done?" tickbox and the next workflow starts.

Now I'm having this particular problem, when I customize the document library's DispForm.aspx in Sharepoint Designer and add a custom Sharepoint control (Custom Document Library listform) it does not contain the Name field (which contains the URL). I can manually add that link in Sharepoint Designer but then the document gets opened in the web version of Word and if the user wants to save it, it saves to the local harddrive, instead of the Document Library.

What am I doing wrong? How can I include the right URL to a document in a customized DispForm of a document library which opens the document in Word and saves to the Document library and creates a draft version?

Suggestions, tips or other solutions VERY welcome!

Erik

Currently using: MOSS 2007, Nintex, Sharepoint Designer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog on how to get an [External Link for Editing a SharePoint Document](http://wiki.threewill.com/display/is/2007/10/14/External+Link+for+Editing+a+SharePoint+Document).  Maybe that can help.

Comment: Your link is broken. Please, don't post answers that rely on an external link for context. This is extremely problematic when an answer is accepted. Would you mind fixing it and at least summarizing the linked text in your answer in order to future proof it?